# Find the canonical Jordan form of $T\left(p(x))=p(x)^{\prime}+2 p(x)\right.$

Tags: linear-algebra

In $P_{2}(R),$ let be $T: P_{2}(R) \rightarrow P_{2}(R),$ the operator given by  $T\left(p(x)=p(x)^{\prime}+2 p(x)\right.$

Find the canonical Jordan form  $J$ for $T$. and find a basis of vectors  $P_{2}(R)$ where the associated matrix to  $T$ is the matrix $J$.

First I find the matrix associated to T it gives me

$M=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ in the canonical basis ${1,x,x^2}$

Then its eigenvalues are 2 with multiplicity 3,

and then the Jordan form is
$J=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 &0  & 2\end{bmatrix}$

and I find the $Ker(M-2I)$  and it gives me $gen={t(1,0,0)}$

and now im stuck finding the other vector to from a basis

Comment: Is not $M=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\0 &2 & 2 \\ 0 & \color{red}{0} & 2\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @aqua yes, is 0 my mistake

Comment: Perhaps you want to find the vector $v$ that gives $(M-2I)v$ equal to your eigenvector? And then ...

Comment: Yes I find gen={t(0,1,0)}

Comment: @TedShifrin the (0,1,0) vector is another vector of the basis, but know how can I find the last vector?

Comment: Repeat the process. Think about what the JCF gives you for equations that the new basis must satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Find a nonzero vector $w \in \Bbb{C}^3 \setminus \ker(M-2I)^2$. Now $$\{u,v,w\}=\{(M-2I)^2w, (M-2I)w, w\}$$
is a basis for $\Bbb{C}^3$ and we have
$$Mu = M(M-2I)^2w = (M-2I)^3w + 2(M-2I)^2w = 2u$$
$$Mv = M(M-2I)w = (M-2I)^2w + 2(M-2I)w = u+2v$$
$$Mw = (M-2I)w+2w =v+2w$$

so it is a Jordan basis for $M$. Picking $w = (0,0,1)$ we get the basis
$$\{u,v,w\} = \{(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,1)\} = \{2,2x,x^2\}.$$